# Bit vs Int vs Long (Performance Issue of Sql )

Tags: sql

They have all different sizes but how about performance issue between each other ? How can we compare them in sql ?

Comment: I believe the performance will be implementation dependent (possibly architecture dependent, too)

Comment: The best way to choose a type is does it store what you need it to store and no more than one you need. If you will only ever store the numbers 1 through 10, pick the smallest integer that will store 1 through 10, throw on a check constraint to keep it just 1 through 10 and call it good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the db vendor's implementation of I/O.

**Edited ("32 bits" changed to "8 bits")**

Many DBs never use anything less than an 8-bit byte to write to disk. For example, the [postgres doco](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/datatype-boolean.html) states that its `boolean` datatype actually takes 1 byte when stored on disk (not 1 bit). All postgres types use a whole number of bytes.

Space on disk is even more important when the field is indexed. Less space means more index entries per I/O page. The less I/O the faster the query - recalling that I/O is roughly 1000 times slower than in-memory work.

Comment: are you sure about this (smaller types upscaled to 32-bit) - can you provide any evidence?

Comment: Most DBs probably never use anything except block size to write to disk, 8KB on MS SQL Server these days, settable on Oracle. However when laying out records in storage, at least some DBs do use different amounts of storage for different types. For example see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827968. Also some DBs will store different numbers with different number of bytes based on value, not on the type, see: http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#varint and http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1856720300346322149

Comment: It really is implementation dependent: "The SQL Server Database Engine optimizes storage of bit columns. If there are 8 or less bit columns in a table, the columns are stored as 1 byte. If there are from 9 up to 16 bit columns, the columns are stored as 2 bytes, and so on." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The main performance issue is likely to stem from the size of the data - the larger the field, the more disk-space it occupies and thus more I/O to read in the data.  When you're dealing with tables with millions of records this could be quite significant.